# Why do I have 2 instances of all of my start-up applications running after a boot?

Tags: linux-mint

Whenever I start my system, I have two instances of all of my apps running. This is very irritating for convenience apps like albert and jetbrains toolbox since I have to manually kill them and restart them.

I think it might have to do with chrome remote desktop, but I'm not sure. The applications are all run under my user name.

I'm using Linux Mint

After trying to disable auto-startup, it didn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Menu, list of programs, right click, check if they are set as 'Start when I login' (or something like, I use the french version 'Lancer lorsque je me connecte'). If checked, uncheck them.

If you set your system as 'Restore previous session', the progs can be called twice, I previously have this behaviour also, and the root cause are still a little bit mysterious !

Comment: I checked the startup applications, and they are definitely there. If I turn them off, will they still start up for me?

Comment: Normally not, but maybe you will have to repeat the uncheck twice

Answer (score -1):

A band-aid solution to this is to include a delay to the additional applications at startup:

Head over to "Startup Applications", select your program and modify the existing command  to

```
sh -c "sleep 5; /path/to/program/executable"
```

Reference: [source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142396/unable-to-execute-two-commands-in-startup-applications)

Comment: Sorry but I just fail to understand how this (supposed to help executing startup applications would help… preventing to launch them twice what actually OP's problem is !

Comment: @MC68020 sorry, I was facing the same issue but on my install of Ubuntu and was using this as a temporary solution so I though of sharing. As it turns out, my issue is self-inflcited due to a GNOME extension which which I installed (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/615/appindicator-support/).
 
In retrospect, my answer is unrelated to OP's question as my situation is completely different. I'll try and be more helpful in future posts, thank you for pointing out the oversight!